# Unable to decipher this error message to find out what to do about it

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, c#-3.0

Anyone know why I'm getting this error message?

**The error message:**

```
{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: tab_group_48.","StackTrace":" at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

**The jQuery:**

The relievant jQuery looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/webservices/minimised.asmx/UpdateState',
    data: '{ strTabID:' + tab + ', strWidgetID:' + widget[1] + ', intState:' + state + ' }',
```

**Data posted to server**

Where in this example:

Data becomes = `{ strTabID:tab_group_48, strWidgetID:portlet_4, intState:0 }`

**The C#:**

And the relievant webservice section c# looks like this:

```
[WebMethod()]
public int UpdateState(string strTabID, string strWidgetID, int intState)
{
    intTabID = Convert.ToInt32(strTabID.Replace("tab_group_", ""));
    strQuery = "update columns set unminimised = @state where tabs_id = @tab and widgets_id = @widget";

    intWidgetID = Convert.ToInt32(strTabID.Replace("portlet_", string.Empty));

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
    {
        using (command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@tab", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = intTabID;
            command.Parameters.Add("@widget", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = intWidgetID;
            command.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = intState;

            connection.Open();
            intAffectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return intAffectedRows;
}
```

Comment: My guess is you have an invalid JSON primitive.

Comment: Yes, but what does that mean and what have I done wrong in the code above to produce that error message?

Comment: The message is telling you exactly what is wrong, Don't be helpless. It takes seconds to look up a list of JSON primitives https://developer.brewmp.com/resources/reference/qualcomm-interface-definition-language-reference/language-mapping/json-language/json-primitive-types].  Is "tab_group_48" a primitive type? No? Then what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON data format is invalid, you need to wrap the values with single quotes e.g.

```
"{ strTabID: '" + tab + "', strWidgetID: '" + widget[1] + "', intState: '" + state + "' }";
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to actually put your tab_group_48 into apostrophes.  Try this:

```
data: "{ strTabID:'" + tab + "', strWidgetID:'" + widget[1] + "', intState:'" + state + "' }"
```